# Array.Filter not woking

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter

When I run an array. filter function, it returns all the array content back without performing the condition check. kindly help. thanks

here is the code

```
const paragraphFields = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ff', 'g'];
 const handleDeleteParagraphFields = (array_index) => {
        paragraphFields.filter((_, index) => index !== array_index);
        console.log(paragraphFields);
        return paragraphFields;
    };
handleDeleteParagraphFields(2)
```

here is the output

```
[
"a",
"b",
"c",
"d",
"ff",
"g"
]
```

Comment: You forgot to pass an argument, so `array_index` is `undefined`

Comment: @CertainPerformance, it is the same when I add the argument. it was an omission from my post and I added it. kindly help look closely into the issue

Comment: You should store the output returned by the filter.

`const paragraphFields = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ff', 'g'];
const handleDeleteParagraphFields = (array_index) => {
    var newArray = paragraphFields.filter((_, index) =>{
     return index !== array_index;
 });

 console.log(newArray);

    return newArray;
};
handleDeleteParagraphFields(2)`

Comment: If you just want remove something from index, why not use array.splice(index, 1) ?

Answer (score 1):

Array filter() returns the result in a new array rather than modifying the data in place:

```
return paragraphFields.filter((_, index) => index !== array_index);
```